# jquery fileupload not keeping variable definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I'm having a problem with the jQuery `fileupload` plugin.

As far as I can tell it *should* work.. but I'm struggling.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form class="dataLookupForm" action="/CustomerDataset/Add" style="display: inline-block;" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="dataLookupForm">
    <label class="btn btn-success">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        <span class="uploadBtnText">Upload New Document</span>
        <input id="fileinput" type="file" onchange='uploadFile(this, event)' class="dataLookupFileUpload" accept=".xlsx,.csv" style="display:none">
    </label>
</form>
```

I'm hiding my `input` field because I want a custom button..

Then my Javascript looks like this:

```
var et = '';
var t = '';

function uploadFile(that, event) {
    et = $(event.target);
    t = that;
    console.log(t.files)
    console.log($(t.form)) //this outputs the form
    et.fileupload({
        url: "/CustomerDataset/Add",
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log($(t.form)) //this DOES NOT output the form.
            $(t.form).find('.uploadBtnText').html('Uploading...')
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(t.form).find('.uploadBtnText').html('Done! Select New File.')
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

So the problem is that variable `t` is not staying defined when it gets to the `fileupload` portion. The first `$(t.form)` console.log is defined, but the second one isn't... Which doesn't make much sense to me.

Another issue I'm having, that might be related, is that the first time I upload a file, it gets to the `console.log`'s in the `uploadFile` function, but it doesn't trigger `et.fileupload`.. the second time I upload a file, it does, however...

Any ideas? I'm really struggling here. Thank you!

Comment: any reason you chose to do an inline `onchange` handler on your input instead of `$('#fileinput').fileupload({` ? from this example https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

Comment: @AndrewLohr I have multiple file uploaders on the same page and I'm trying to select the one that was chosen..

Comment: You can use a class on each input and then use `$('.fileinput').fileupload({` instead of `#` use `.` to target all inputs with that class name. Then `this` inside the `done` function (in the link I posted above) will refer to the clicked one

Comment: @AndrewLohr, I shoud've also mentioned they are all dynamically loaded and that solution doesn't seem to work for dynamically generated content.